How to pass data from layout to component in livewire v3
How can I pass data from layout to component in livewire?
I want to pass data from layout to $slot.
My layout is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased">

<div>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>

@livewireScripts
</body>
</html>


Please explain better: what data do you want pass to the slot? Can you modify the question by adding an example?

I want to add $socil_links = Social::all(). I want to pass social links, because all pages have social links section

Is this what you want?

But I cant pass data to layout component from layout class.

I had a similar solution to find for 'general counters' to offload DB interaction at every page request.
There are 2 solutions:

make use of sharing data with all views
make use of session() data values

It's unclear if the data you want to pass is session or sharing related. The best choice is yours to make.
